# Lower Bound of the inner product of two semi-positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, normed-spaces, symmetric-matrices

Let $A,B$ be (real )semi-positive definite symmetric matrix of the same dimension $n$. If $(a_i),(b_i)$ are eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$, both ordered ascendingly, then $\langle A,B\rangle\triangleq\mathrm{Tr}(AB)\geq \sum_ia_ib_{n-i}$. I would want to know if there  are lower bounds of the inner product given by the inner product of the eigenvectors?

For example, let $n=5$ and $A$ and $B$ be given with eigenvalues $(0,a,a,a,a)$ and $(0,b,b,b,b)$ and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the unit eigenvector of $A$ and $B$ with eigenvalue $0$. Then we have

> $\langle A,B\rangle\geq 4ab|\langle \alpha ,\beta\rangle|\tag 1$

For the case when $A,B$ are given with eigenvalues $(0,a_1,a_1,a_2,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_1,b_2,b_2)$, I guess we have (but I haven't figured out a proof)

> $\langle A,B\rangle\geq 4\sqrt{a_1a_2b
> _1b_2}|\langle \alpha ,\beta\rangle|\tag 2$

I want to know whether $(2)$ is correct, and whether there are some more general inequalities? I guess there would be a lower bound of $\langle A,B\rangle $ given by a combination of $\langle 
 \alpha_i,\beta_j\rangle$ and $\mathrm{Tr}(A)\mathrm{Tr}(B)$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Consider matrix $A=\operatorname{diag}(a_i)_{n\times n}$ and $B=g\operatorname{diag}(b_j)_{n\times n}g^T$, where $g=(g_{ij})_{n\times n}$ is an orthogonal matrix. The question is asking for the lower bound of $tr(\operatorname{diag}(a_i)(g_{ij})\operatorname{diag}(b_j)(g_{ij})^T)=\sum_{ij}a_i b_j g_{ij}^2$ with expression $g_{ij}=\langle 
 \alpha_i,\beta_j\rangle$.